# Finding all n-lets (pairs, triplets, quadruplets, etc.) of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, permutation

I want to write a function that takes in a list of integers (e.g. `L = [0,1,-1]`) and a single integer (e.g. `n = 3`) and returns all of the (e.g. triplets) of that list: `[0,0,0],[0,0,1],...[-1,-1,-1]` of which there will be `len(L)**n`. If I'm committed to `n=3`, I could do:

```
np.array(np.meshgrid(L,L,L)).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

However, if I want to change that 3 to a different number, I would need to enter my list into meshgrid n times. Is there a slick way of doing this that will work for arbitrary `n`? I hope what I'm trying to do makes some sense. It seems like the sort of thing a function would already exist for, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `itertools.product` has a handy `repeat` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of `L` repeated `n` times via: `[L for _ in range(n)]`. Then just dereference this list to the `meshgrid` function using the star operator. [What does the star operator mean, in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)

```
n = 2
>>> np.array(np.meshgrid(*[L for _ in range(n)])).T.reshape(-1, n)
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 0, -1],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 1, -1],
       [-1,  0],
       [-1,  1],
       [-1, -1]])
```

Comment: Or simply `np.array(np.meshgrid(*n*(L,))).T.reshape(-1,n)`.